# Android - DJI UX SDK and Espresso - VerifyError

Tags: gradle, android-espresso, dji-sdk

What modules do I have to exclude in my `build.gradle` file in order to get rid of the following error:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class dji.keysdk.CameraKey due to bad method void dji.keysdk.CameraKey.<init>(dji.sdksharedlib.keycatalog.DJISDKCacheKey) (declaration of 'dji.keysdk.CameraKey' appears in /data/app/pl.company.dev.test-1/base.apk:classes3.dex)
at dji.ux.widget.FPVOverlayWidget.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
```

My build.gradle file contains the following DJI dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.dji:dji-uxsdk:4.9'
compileOnly 'com.dji:dji-sdk-provided:4.9'
androidTestImplementation 'com.dji:dji-uxsdk:4.9'
```

I want to write some Espresso tests for the activity that uses the DJI UX SDK
What I already tried and didn't work:

- rebuild app
- invalidate caches and restart in Android Studio
- delete folders: `build`, `.idea`, `.gradle`
- the whole process on another PC
- exclude some unneeded dependencies from the DJI SDK

Answer (score 0):

You should not include the same dependency in the app and the tests.

Everything in the app is already in the classpath of the instrumentation tests.

In your specific case, remove
 `androidTestImplementation 'com.dji:dji-uxsdk:4.9'`